# Unable to remove Camel Quartz route

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have setup an endpoint like this:

```
from("quartz://GroupName/TimerName?stateful=true&cron=0 0/1 * * * ?")
.to("someProcessorBean");
```

In order to make sure there are no static endpoints, I do:

```
for (Endpoint endpoint : camelContext.getEndpoints()) {
  camelContext.removeEndpoint(endpoint);
}
```

When trying to programmatically removing the route, I'm doing the following:

```
camelContext.stop();
camelContext.removeRoute(routeId);
```

However, there are no endpoints returned here.

Even after doing this, the job continues to run on schedule.  How can I unschedule it when removing the route?

I'm using camel-quartz 2.22.2 with quartz 1.8.6

Here are the logs from the shutdown and then start of Context.

## Shutting down endpoint

```
12:22:13,008 DEBUG [DefaultManagementAgent] Unregistered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=CamelContext-MyContext_6.1.1-SNAPSHOT,type=endpoints,name="quartz://MY_GROUP/MY_NAME\?cron=0+0%2F1+\*+\*+\*+%3F&stateful=true"
12:22:13,008 INFO  [SpringCamelContext] Apache Camel 2.22.2 (CamelContext: CamelContext-MyContext_6.1.1-SNAPSHOT) is shutting down
12:22:13,008 INFO  [DefaultShutdownStrategy] Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
```

## Stopping route

```
12:22:13,033 INFO  [DefaultShutdownStrategy] Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
12:22:13,033 DEBUG [DefaultExecutorServiceManager] Created new ThreadPool for source: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy@3a44287c with name: ShutdownTask. -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@3fc7873f[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][ShutdownTask]
12:22:13,034 DEBUG [DefaultShutdownStrategy] There are 1 routes to shutdown
12:22:13,034 INFO  [DefaultShutdownStrategy] Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
12:22:13,034 INFO  [SpringCamelContext] Route: MY_CATEGORY.MY_NAME is stopped, was consuming from: quartz://MY_GROUP/MY_NAME?cron=0+0%2F1+*+*+*+%3F&stateful=true
12:22:13,034 DEBUG [RouteService] Shutting down services on route: MY_CATEGORY.MY_NAME
12:22:13,034 DEBUG [RouteService] Shutting down child service on route: MY_CATEGORY.MY_NAME -> FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[DelegateSync[com.crlcorp.oasis.routing.utils.LauncherErrorHandler@7ccfd046]]]
12:22:13,034 DEBUG [RouteService] Shutting down child service on route: MY_CATEGORY.MY_NAME -> DelegateSync[com.crlcorp.oasis.routing.utils.LauncherErrorHandler@7ccfd046]
12:22:13,034 DEBUG [RouteService] Shutting down child service on route: MY_CATEGORY.MY_NAME -> Channel[DelegateSync[com.crlcorp.oasis.routing.utils.LauncherErrorHandler@7ccfd046]]
12:22:13,034 INFO  [SpringCamelContext] Route: MY_CATEGORY.MY_NAME is shutdown and removed, was consuming from: quartz://MY_GROUP/MY_NAME?cron=0+0%2F1+*+*+*+%3F&stateful=true
```

## Starting context with "no routes"

```
12:22:13,078 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v1.8.6) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler-CamelContext-MyContext_6.1.1-SNAPSHOT' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

12:22:13,078 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler-CamelContext-MyContext_6.1.1-SNAPSHOT' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
12:22:13,078 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.6
12:22:13,078 DEBUG [QuartzComponent] Using SchedulerFactory org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory@5efaa50e to get/create Scheduler org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler@6d39162c(0x6d39162c)
12:22:13,078 INFO  [QuartzComponent] Starting Quartz scheduler: DefaultQuartzScheduler-CamelContext-MyContext_6.1.1-SNAPSHOT
12:22:13,078 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler-CamelContext-MyContext_6.1.1-SNAPSHOT_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
12:22:13,078 DEBUG [DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy] Load performance statistics disabled
12:22:13,078 INFO  [SpringCamelContext] Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started
12:22:13,078 INFO  [SpringCamelContext] Apache Camel 2.22.2 (CamelContext: CamelContext-MyContext_6.1.1-SNAPSHOT) started in 0.036 seconds
```

## Quartz job comes back from the dead

```
12:22:13,507 DEBUG [SimpleThreadPool] WorkerThread is shut down.
12:23:00,002 DEBUG [SimpleJobFactory] Producing instance of Job 'DEFAULT.quartz-endpoint1', class=org.apache.camel.component.quartz.StatefulCamelJob
12:23:00,002 DEBUG [JobRunShell] Calling execute on job DEFAULT.quartz-endpoint1
12:23:00,002 DEBUG [CamelJob] Looking up existing QuartzEndpoint with trigger MY_NAME.MY_GROUP
12:23:00,002 DEBUG [QuartzEndpoint] Firing Quartz Job with context: JobExecutionContext: trigger: 'MY_GROUP.MY_NAME job: DEFAULT.quartz-endpoint1 fireTime: 'Mon Jan 07 12:23:00 CST 2019 scheduledFireTime: Mon Jan 07 12:23:00 CST 2019 previousFireTime: 'Mon Jan 07 12:22:00 CST 2019 nextFireTime: Mon Jan 07 12:24:00 CST 2019 isRecovering: false refireCount: 0
```

Comment: do you let camel start the quartz scheduler? If so I would expect `camelContext.stop()` to stop the scheduler.

Comment: Me too.  I'm dynamically adding it to the context, but stopping and removing the route is not to enough to stop the quartz scheduler.

Comment: Can you add the output you see on the logs (INFO level) for `org.quartz.*` and `org.apache.camel.*`?

Comment: @pcoates Added.  Even though it states "Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started", there is still a CamelJob hanging out in the background

Comment: I've chased down the problem to the fact that there are two schedulers and only one is getting shut down when I stop the component

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

Upgrade to camel-quartz2 instead of camel-quartz.

## Option 2

The problem relates to the Quartz Component creating two schedulers and only shutting down one when stopping the route.  This may be due to the fact that the route is stateful.  In order to fix this, you can manually access all the schedulers related to the component and stop all of the jobs.

```
log.info("Removing existing endpoints");
for (Endpoint endpoint : camelContext.getEndpoints()) {
  log.info("Removing: " + endpoint.getEndpointUri());
    
  if (endpoint instanceof QuartzEndpoint) {
    QuartzEndpoint quartzEndpoint = (QuartzEndpoint) endpoint;
    
    SchedulerFactory factory = quartzEndpoint.getComponent().getFactory();
    log.debug("Found factory " + factory);
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Collection<Scheduler> allSchedulers = factory.getAllSchedulers();
    for (Scheduler scheduler : allSchedulers) {
      log.debug("Found Quartz Scheduler" + scheduler.getSchedulerName());
      for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {
        for (String jobName : scheduler.getJobNames(groupName)) {
          log.debug(String.format("Unscheduling job %s.%s", groupName, jobName));
          scheduler.deleteJob(jobName, groupName);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  camelContext.removeEndpoint(endpoint);
}
    
log.info("Stopping Camel Context");
camelContext.stop();
    
log.info("Removing existing routes");
RoutesDefinition routes = getRouteCollection();
routes.getOnExceptions().clear();
for (RouteDefinition route : routes.getRoutes()) {
  String routeId = route.getId();
  try {
    log.info("Removing: " + routeId);
    camelContext.removeRoute(routeId);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("Could not stop route" + routeId + ": " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
routes.getRoutes().clear();
```